# How do I associate multiple nodes to a user?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have some users, and I have a "product" content type, which has the following fields: "name," "type," and "description."

I want to associate specific nodes of this content type to a user. How do you suggest I should do this?

Shall I create a new table and store the user and the product ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module for handling relationships between entities for Drupal 7 which shows great promise called [relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation). At the current time it's still in alpha and I haven't tested it out for a while, so I am not sure where it is at. When I last tried it out, it wasn't quite suitable.

A more stable version which could be made obsolete by the relation module is the [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) module, which is a port of the Drupal 6 CCK node reference field. I've used that with great success.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I have tried references module, however I get the error 416 - `Requested Range Not Satisfiable

None of the range-specifier values in the Range request-header field overlap the current extent of the selected resource.` When you played with this module it was ok?

Comment: Resolved: The problem was that I have not views installed... strangely he has not complained about it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly look into using a 'user reference', part of CCK in Drupal 6 to link products to users.

Comment: Might not work so well on Drupal 7 ;)

Comment: missed the D7 tag, doh!